# Function returning a value not using copy/move or copy elision

Tags: c++

The test function is returning a value without using a copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment operator or copy elision (disabled in g++ 4.8.4 via -fno-elide-constructors)

```
struct Test
{
    Test() {}
    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test(Test&&) = delete;
    Test& operator = (const Test&) = delete;
    Test& operator = (Test&&) = delete;
    void fn(){}
};

Test test() {
    // error: use of deleted function ‘Test::Test(Test&&)’
    // return Test{};

    // However, this compiles (g++ 4.8.4 and g++ 6.1.0)
    return {};
}

int main() {
    test().fn();

    // In any case
    // error: use of deleted function ‘Test::Test(Test&&)’
    // Test t{test()};
}
```

Is the code valid and if so, what are the effects of `return {}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[stmt.return]/1** ... A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list...

Comment: Makes sense - made a test with a constructor Test(int).